# Notepad++ Replace square brackets with Regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

How to make this

```
$var[somevalue];
```

to

```
$var['somevalue'];
```

with notepad++ (replace)
I've found this to find the `\[somevalue\]`:

```
^\[^\\\]\\\[\\n\]\*(?:\\r?\\n\[^\\\]\\\[\\n\]\*)?\\\]|\\\[\[^\\\]\\\[\\n\]\*(?:\\r?\\n\[^\\\]\\\[\\n\]\*)?\\\]?
```

but had no idea how to add the single quotes to the value.

Thanks

Try to find a solution by google and testing but got not the right solution

Comment: @Gilles provides good advice on selecting an answer. I would add to that there is no rush to select one. Quick selections can discourage some readers from posting a better answer and if an incorrect answer is posted the flaw may be less likely to be detected by readers if that answer has already been selected. Most experienced SO members generally wait at least a few hours before making a selection. Some wait long enough to allow members from around the world to view the question. Regardless, don't forget to select the answer you find most helpful (provided at least one is helpful).

Answer (score 1):

**Find**:

```
\[([^\]]+)
```

**Replace**::

```
['\1'
```

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Regex | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `\[` | Matches a literal `[` |
| `([^\]]+)` | Matches any character except literal `]` one or more times and stores result in `\1` |

Answer (score 0):

You can replace (zero-width) matches of the regular expression

```
(?<=\[)|(?=\])
```

with a single quote.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BNbXeP/1)

Notepad++'s regex engine supports *positive lookaheads* (here `(?=\])`) and (fixed length) *positive lookbehinds* (here `(?<=\[)`). Think of `(?<=\[)` as the location after `'['` and before the letter that follows `'['` and think of matches of `(?=\])` as the location before `']'` and after the letter that precedes `']'`.

---

The above will replace `"a[bc"` with `"a['bc'"` and `"ab]c"` with `"ab']c'"`, which may not be desired.

To only make replacements when both left and right brackets are present use the regular expression

```
\[(.*?)\]
```

and replace the match with

```
'\1'
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/38onJ9/1)

The question mark in `.*?` causes `.*` to match as few characters as possible, so it will not match `']'`. By contrast, `.*` matches as many characters as possible. Therefore, if the string were `'a[b]c[d]e'`, `.*?` would match `'[b]'` and then `'[d]'`, whereas `.*?` would match `'[b]c[d]'`.

If desired, `.*?` could in most cases be replaced with `[^\]]*`. The only difference is that the later matches line terminators whereas the former does not. One could even use `[^\[\]]*` to guard against the ill-formed string `"ab[c[d]e"` being replaced with `"ab['c[d']e"`.